# Calculate the optimal grid layout dimensions for a given amount of plots in R

Tags: r, rows, dimensions

I have 12 plots in ggplot, and I am arranging them with grid.arrange. I manually set the number of rows in the grid to 4, the number of columns to 3. Since 3 x 4 = 12, this works like a charm.

But what if I have an arbitrary number of plots? Say 13... How would I programmatically find the number of rows and columns to use that makes the entire plot the most "square-like" shape?

I'd like to do this in R.

**Update**
Link to data: http://github.com/ngfrey/DataGenii/blob/master/exampleMedicalData.csv

Here is the code I was working on this morning.  Hopefully it will provide a more illustrative example. Note how I set the number of rows and columns in the `return(list(plots=plots, numrow=4, numcol=3))` part of the function:

```
makePlots<- function(fdf){
idx<- which(sapply(fdf, is.numeric))
idx<- data.frame(idx)
names(idx)<- "idx"
idx$names<- rownames(idx)
plots<- list()

for(i in 2:length(idx$idx)) {
  varname<- idx$names[i]
  mydata<- fdf[, idx$names[i]]
  mydata<- data.frame(mydata)
  names(mydata)<- varname
  g<- ggplot(data=mydata, aes_string(x=varname) )
  g<- g + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), color="black", fill='skyblue')+ geom_density() + xlab(paste(varname))
  print(g)


  plots<- c(plots, list(g))
}

return(list(plots=plots, numrow=4, numcol=3 ))
}
res<- makePlots(fdf)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(res$plots, nrow=res$numrow, ncol=res$numcol))
```

Comment: plot are generated and you do not know in advance how many they will be?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific by what you mean by square-like, otherwise `ceiling(sqrt(13))`?

Comment: I am given multiple datasets daily, each with an unknown number of numerical variables. I want to create a grid of density plots for each numerical variable in the respective dataset.  I'll add an example in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got this bad boy to work:
(I could still tighten up the axis labels, and probably compress the first 2 if statements in the `makePlots()` function so it would run faster, but I'll tackle that at a later date/post)

```
library(gmp)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

############
factors <- function(n)
{
   if(length(n) > 1) 
   {
      lapply(as.list(n), factors)
   } else
   {
      one.to.n <- seq_len(n)
      one.to.n[(n %% one.to.n) == 0]
   }
}


###########
makePlots<- function(fdf){
idx<- which(sapply(fdf, is.numeric))
idx<- data.frame(idx)
names(idx)<- "idx"
idx$names<- rownames(idx)
plots<- list()

for(i in 2:length(idx$idx)) {
  varname<- idx$names[i]
  mydata<- fdf[, idx$names[i]]
  mydata<- data.frame(mydata)
  names(mydata)<- varname
  g<- ggplot(data=mydata, aes_string(x=varname) )
  g<- g + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), color="black", fill='skyblue')+ geom_density() + xlab(paste(varname))
  print(g)


  plots<- c(plots, list(g))
}

numplots<- 0
#Note: The reason I put in length(idx$idx)-1 is because the first column is the row indicies, which are usually numeric ;)
#isprime returns 0 for non-prime numbers, 2 for prime numbers
if(length(idx$idx) == 2){
  numplots<- length(idx$idx)
  ncolx<- 1
  nrowx<- 2
} else if(length(idx$idx)==3){
  numplots<- length(idx$idx)
  ncolx<- 1
  nrowx<- 3
} else if(isprime((length(idx$idx)-1)) !=0){ 
  numplots<- length(idx$idx)
  facts<- factors(numplots)
  ncolx<- facts[length(facts)/2]
  nrowx<- facts[(length(facts)/2) + 1]

} else{numplots<- (length(idx$idx)-1)
  facts<- factors(numplots)
  ncolx<- facts[length(facts)/2]
  nrowx<- facts[(length(facts)/2) + 1]}

if(abs(nrowx-ncolx)>2){
  ncolx<- ncolx+1
  nrowx<- ceiling(numplots/ncolx)
}


return(list(plots=plots, numrow=nrowx, numcol=ncolx ))
}
res<- makePlots(fdf)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(res$plots, nrow=res$numrow, ncol=res$numcol))
```

Answer (score 1):

`?n2mfrow` finds a default layout for you; in fact, it's already used by `grid.arrange` if `nrow` and `ncol` are missing

```
grid.arrange(grobs = replicate(7, rectGrob(), simplify=FALSE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In practice there are a limited number of plots that can reasonably be displayed and few arrangements that are aesthetically pleasing, so you could just tabulate.

However, what we can do is specify a tolerance for the ratio of the larger dimension to the smaller. Then we find the closest two numbers that factor our target. If these are within tolerance, we are done. Otherwise, we add waste to our target. This terminates at the sooner of finding a suitable pair or at the next largest square. (Tolerance should be > 1).

Smallest of the closest two numbers that factor a given `n`

```
fact<-function(n) {
  k<-floor(sqrt(n));
  for(i in k:1) {if (n%%i == 0) return(i)}
}
```

Search for a near square within tolerance

```
nearsq<-function(n,tol=5/3+0.001) {
  m<-ceiling(sqrt(n))^2;
  for(i in n:m) {
    a<-fact(i);
    b<-i/a;
    if(b/a < tol) return(c(a,b))
  }
}
```

Examples

```
#probably too many plots
nearsq(83)
#> [1]  8 11

#a more reasonable range of plots, tabulated
cbind(12:36,t(Vectorize(nearsq)(12:36)))
```

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]   12    3    4
 [2,]   13    3    5
 [3,]   14    3    5
 [4,]   15    3    5
 [5,]   16    4    4
 [6,]   17    4    5
 [7,]   18    4    5
 [8,]   19    4    5
 [9,]   20    4    5
[10,]   21    4    6
[11,]   22    4    6
[12,]   23    4    6
[13,]   24    4    6
[14,]   25    5    5
[15,]   26    5    6
[16,]   27    5    6
[17,]   28    5    6
[18,]   29    5    6
[19,]   30    5    6
[20,]   31    5    7
[21,]   32    5    7
[22,]   33    5    7
[23,]   34    5    7
[24,]   35    5    7
[25,]   36    6    6
```

Comment: Thank You! I also found another way to tackle this. I'll post my own answer too!